# Outputting Spring Boot log In docker Container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I am looking to just link the log to Spring boot admin. But using the simple logging properties although it work in a jar outside of docker. it doesn't output anything in the container. I tried a mix of permission with no avail.

I tried different distro in docker but no joy.

I posted the code to this address and use just a basic example based of https://start.spring.io/ to simplify things.

https://github.com/peans99/java

the only thing in the application.properties file is :

```
logging.file.path=logs
```

dockerfile

```
FROM amd64/alpine:3.12.3
#installing Java
RUN apk add openjdk11
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
RUN chown -R spring:spring /opt
RUN chmod 777 -R /opt
USER spring:spring
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} /opt/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/opt/app.jar", "--trace"]
```

Thanks for your help